# FOG to deploy only the first partition of HDD

Tags: imaging, disk-cloning, ghost

i am using  [FOG](http://www.fogproject.org/) (free opensource ghost) for cloning computers
i want to image only the first partition of my HDD which would be my system drive c: 
i have tried all the options size partition(resizable),multiple partition single disk etc
but every time i deploy the image data in the d: is also lost.
how can i deploy images so that only my system drive c: re-written
and i keep my data intact on d: as it is.
any ideas ??